# How to draw differential geometry diagrams like the one below?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, notes

I am making notes on the subject and I have to make too many figures of the following kind. How do I do this?[image: Mani]

Comment: The short answer is to use a package like [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). I should warn you however that some people take exception to questions of the form "Please draw this for me". You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: I am new to latex and I don't know how to draw anything. With an example I can start tweaking and learn to draw figures of this type.

Comment: There are hundreds of different examples in the manual, and also here on the site. While not exactly your image, some inspiration can probably be found in [How to draw this figure in a better way (mapping between domains)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/291450) and [tikz diagram showing range, domain, and co-domain of a function](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56139) and [Drawing a mapping between arbitrary domains](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113731)

Comment: Which manual are you talking about?

Comment: Oops, sorry, was kind of following Andrew's comment: [TikZ's manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative tool is [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) with `lualatex` and the [luamplib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en) package.

[image]

Here's a routine to draw manifolds as general randomised ellipses.  Drawing labels, arrows, and boxes, etc is covered in the manuals and tutorials linked above.  As a bonus I've added the torus hole too.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef manifold(expr a,b,rho) = 
    (for t=0 upto 7: 
       right scaled (a+rho*normaldeviate) rotated 45t .. 
     endfor cycle) yscaled (b/a)
enddef;
randomseed:=1855.10574;

beginfig(1);
path M, N, torus_edge_lower, torus_edge_upper, torus_hole;

M = manifold(90,60,10);  
N = manifold(80,80,3) shifted 240 right rotated 10;

torus_edge_lower = quartercircle scaled 80 rotated 225 shifted center M shifted (-25,15);
torus_edge_upper = point 1/3 of torus_edge_lower 
              {direction 1/3 of torus_edge_lower rotated 80} 
                .. point 5/3 of torus_edge_lower;
torus_hole = buildcycle(torus_edge_lower,torus_edge_upper);

fill M withcolor .9[blue,white];
unfill torus_hole;
draw M; 
draw torus_edge_lower; 
draw torus_edge_upper;
label(btex $M$ etex, point 7 of M shifted (-6,16));

fill N withcolor .9[green,white];
draw N;
label(btex $N$ etex, point 7 of N shifted (-6,16));
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

To draw a manifold you can use `plot coordinates` with `smooth` option, and you can play with the `tension` parameter. Or you can use the [hobby](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby) package.

To draw a hole you can use the `arc` command.

Here is a starting example :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[smooth cycle,tension=.7] plot coordinates{(-1,0) (0.5,2) (2,2) (4,3) (4.5,0)};
    \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
    \draw (A) arc(140:40:1) (A) arc(-140:-20:1) (A) arc(-140:-160:1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]